# Is there a way to evaluate variables inside a function which are not function arguments when calling toString method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, eval

I'm generating PDF files in nodejs using [pdfmake](http://pdfmake.org/playground.html). I'm generating tables, so for some columns I need to send formatting function.

For example, if rows have property `employee`, whose value can be something like:

`{id: 1, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Johnson'}`,

For displaying this column I use following formatting function:

`` employee => `${employee.firstName} ${employee.lastName}` ``

So to my nodejs backend, I'm sending this function as string. Calling `toString` on this function returns the same text from above with quotes:

`` "employee => `${employee.firstName} ${employee.lastName}`" ``

Then I execute this function with arguments I get from database. I do this by calling `eval`

`` eval(`(${fnString})({id: 1, firstName: 'Test', lastName: 'Test'})`) ``

And this works fine when only variables inside a function are it's arguments.

---

So this is my question:

Say I have code like this:

```
const prefix = 'X'
const fn = employee => `${prefix} ${employee.firstName} ${employee.lastName}`
```

`fn.toString()` evaluates to:

`` "employee => `${prefix} ${employee.firstName} ${employee.lastName}`" ``

But I need it to be like this:

`` "employee => `X ${employee.firstName} ${employee.lastName}`" ``

because I won't have access to `prefix` variable, I only send function as string to the nodejs.

Is there a way to evaluate variables inside a function when calling toString method?

Yes, I know, I could also send prefix to nodejs, but this is not really a nice solution, and sometimes formatting function can depend on many variables which are in the scope where function is defined.

*Yes, I know I shouldn't be using eval*

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty solution is to simply use string manipulation and invent your own syntax:

```
const fn = employee => `%PREFIX% ${employee.firstName} ${employee.lastName}`
let fnString = fn.toString();
fnString = fnString.replace('%PREFIX%', prefix);
```

Basically, you're inventing your own templating language like [handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/) or React's [jsx](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) or [ejs](https://ejs.co).

Personally I have a feeling that there's a better way to do this but I can't think of any quick fix without overhauling your entire architecture. I guess if it's good enough for React/Angular etc. it should be good enough for you.